# Redis XREAD and XREVRANGE in Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, stream, redis-streams

```
client.xrevrange('TEST_STREAM','count 1',function (err,Data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);  
} else
console.log("Data from stream is:",Data);
  });
```

I'm trying to read the data from Redis stream and this line is giving me this error:

> ERROR:" ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'xrevrange'
> command"

I need help regarding this error or if there is another way to read data from Redis stream do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some arguments, try :

```
client.xrevrange('TEST_STREAM','+', '-', 'COUNT', 1,function (err,Data) { 
 if (err) {
    return console.error(err);  
} else
console.log("Data from stream is:",Data);
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).